# Are there solvable lattice field theories?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lattice-model

In lattice QCD, correlations functions are calculated by Monte Carlo integration of the path integral. Are there other field theories whose **discretized versions** allow lattice correlators to be evaluated analytically? I know there are solvable (continuum) quantum field theories, but wonder if there are solvable lattice field theories.

Comment: Do examples in 2d spacetime count?  Here's one: Gross and Witten (1980), Possible third-order phase transition in the large-N lattice gauge theory, Phys Rev D 21:446 ([link to pdf](http://theory.fi.infn.it/colomo/random_matrices/Gross-Witten_80.pdf)).